# fosrestbundle, using a twig view in json _format resultat in a htmlentities encoded response

Tags: json, twig, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle,
for the `newRessourceAction`, I'd like to generate a json version of the form that I could use has a template in order to POST a new one.

For this purpose, I've been testing several ways to return a json reponse, but in every case, my json string end to be jsonencoded by the FOSRestBundle. Here is an example :

```
#in the controller
/**
 * @View()
 */
public function newFooAction(Request $request) {
    $_format = $request->attributes->get('_format');
    $foo = new Foo();
    $form = $this->createForm(FooType::class, $foo, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('post_foo', ['_format' => $_format]),'method' => 'POST',]);
    return ['form' => $form];
}


#in the foo.json.twig
{{ form | serialize('json') }}
```

the output tends to be like that (notice the `&quot;`) :

```
{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference for `serialize` in Twig's documentation. Is that a custom function you made?

Can you try this to see what happens:

```
{{ form|json_encode() }}
```

Here is the documentation for it: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html

Try that, and let us know the results. I haven't verified this, so I'm not sure if it will work for you.

Comment: In order to serialize my entities into a proper json, I use the [JMSSerialiserBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle), wich result in the `| serialize('json')`. if I use `|json_encode()`, I've got the same problem of htmlentities.